# SQL Count error from within Python script. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, select, count

Here's the SQL command I'm running. The result I keep getting back is **None**, but I know for sure there are at least 1300 records that match these conditions. Any ideas?

```
count_unchecked = "SELECT COUNT(website_url) FROM url_list WHERE http_response=200 AND is_website IS NULL"
number_unchecked = mycursor.execute(count_unchecked)
mydb.close()
    print("This program will attempt to identify which of the URLs collected are camped.")
    print("Currently, there are", number_unchecked, "records that have not been checked.")
    urls_to_check = input("How many URLs would you like to check?")
```

I chose to count the website_url column because every record has that one populated. Any ideas why it's returning **None**?

FINAL SOLUTION:
Here's the code for the final solution! I learned that fetchone returns a tuple, so to make it look as clean as possible I have to reference the first element in the tuple.

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

count_unchecked = "SELECT COUNT(website_url) FROM url_list WHERE http_response=200 AND is_website IS NULL"
mycursor.execute(count_unchecked)
fetched = mycursor.fetchone()
number_unchecked = fetched[0]
mydb.close()
```

Comment: Maybe the condition `is_website` should be `is not null`?

Comment: Are you looking for URL's that do not have a website? You may also have to quote 200 depending on your DB

Comment: The rest of this script will populate the is_website field. So this part of it will tell the user how many URLs need to be checked to see if they're just being squatted. Really all I'm doing is counting how many records don't have the anything in the is_website field, which by default is set to NULL.

Comment: Removed the http_response condition to check if that was the problem. Just using the is_website IS NULL condition produces the same results.

Comment: Wow. Even taking out ALL the conditions produces None.

Comment: And how are you running the query?

Comment: @jccampanero Added more of the script for context. I'm sure this is some kind of data type that I'm misusing, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you must fetch the results because by default `cursor.execute` returns `None`:

```py
mycursor.execute(count_unchecked)
row = mycursor.fetchone()
number_unchecked = row[0]
```

Please, see the [relevant documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html).